# Data Validation Criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I am currently trying to change cell validations cell range in Google Spreadsheet base upon a cell's input.

For instance, if A1 = 123 then have B1 (which is the data verification cell) pull from C1:C20, but if A1 = 456 then have B1 cell pull criteria from D1:20.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

'Yes', at least after a fashion. For practical purposes it seems 'not yet'.

Create the requirement in Excel (see dependent drop down list [eg](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html)) and import into New Google spreadsheets. This bypasses the failure to accept something like `INDIRECT("range"&A1")` as the `Criteria:` for a List from a range and does not show which entries are valid when the drop-down arrow in the cell is clicked (just `Loading...`) but does warn of/reject unacceptable values and accept valid ones.